# How we can avoid rebooting the system after partition change with fdisk?

Tags: linux, kernel, partition

When modifying the partition table, `fdisk` usually returns the following error message:

> WARNING: Re-reading the partition table failed with error 16: Device or resource busy.

The kernel still uses the old table. The new table will be used at the next reboot.

Is there any method to avoid the reboot?

Comment: depending of the partion you modify maybe `mount -a` could do the trick

Answer (score 8):

There is a solution using partprobe from parted software. More information here: http://www.gnu.org/software/parted/

After using your `fdisk` command and having done your modifications, do a `partprobe` or `partprobe /dev/sdx` and it should inform the kernel of the change without reboot.

Comment: Resolved and worked with 'partprobe'  by using the command:
# /sbin/partprobe